# The type freemarker.core.Configurable cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, java-8, freemarker

In sts I'm doing some sample freemarker maven  project when I'm configuring I'm getting following error.

> The type `freemarker.core.Configurable` cannot be resolved. It is
>   indirectly referenced from required `.class` files

Below is my code snippet:

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setClassForTemplateLoading(App.class, "/");
```

Comment: Check that you have all of the library's dependencies.

Comment: Are you sure it is related to Apache Spark?

Comment: @killjoy Yes I have all library in my path

Comment: @jgp i don't think so

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved the dependency jar file in .m2 folder was corrupted I manually downloaded a jar file from the maven repository. Now it is working fine